# Creating a keyboard shortcut to send an email with pynput and pywin32

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, win32com, pynput

I'm trying to set up a keyboard shortcut to send an email from outlook using pywin32. I'm getting this error, I'd guess it's because pynput and win32com are both accessing the windows API? But I'm new to windows programming and python so any help would be appreciated.

```
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
  File "C:\Users\lukew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\lukew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Users\lukew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)
```

```
    import win32com.client as win32
    from pynput import keyboard
    
    class Action:
    
        def send_mail(self):
            outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
            mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
            mail.To = 'Luke Wood'
            mail.Subject = 'Mail subject'
            mail.Body = 'Hello'
    
            mail.Send()
    
    class Hot:
    
        def __init__(self, action):
            self.action = action
            self.listener = keyboard.Listener(win32_event_filter=self.win32_event_filter)
            with self.listener as ml:
                ml.join()
    
        def down(self, key):
            if key == 162:
                self.action.send_mail()
    
        def win32_event_filter(self, msg, data):
            if msg == 256:
                self.down(data.vkCode)
            return True
    
    action = Action()
    Hot(action)
    
    input()
```

Windows 10 x64 - Python 3.8.2  -  Outlook 2019

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `win32`, you can use `redmail` to send the outlook email. Note that you'll have to install `redmail` first to be able to use it. Here's a short example:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
from redmail import outlook

def on_press(key):
    if key.char == 's':
        outlook.user_name = '5rod@hotmail.com'
        outlook.password = 'mysecretpassword1234'

        outlook.send(
            receivers=['someone@example.com'],
            subject='test',
            text='This is a test'
        )

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```